# Problem with WMD editor

Tags: editor, wmd

Has anyone used wmd editor?

I am having a problem with the editor in a form. Its not being configured as the editor after setting up in a form. Only the text area is shown with no editing options. The form has already many controls and other scripting files included. I am using IE 7. Its working in another form which has only a text area in it.

Is this due to any conflict with other scripting files or any other issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have used WMD ([over here](http://discordianquotes.com/)), though I don't know that it's really relevant; without a lot more detail, the advice I can give you is pretty general.

That being: yes, it probably is a conflict with some other element you're pulling into your form, and I recommend that you test this by commenting out everything but the WMD support, seeing if it works, and if it does, then re-adding things one at a time until you find one that breaks it.  Then see if you can resolve the conflict in some way.

Comment: But the form contains more than 100 elements.

Comment: Then add them back in in groups of 10.

Comment: Or better yet, do binary elimination. It will take you 8 or 9 tries only.